# failure to install airflow helm chart on GKE due to failing migration

Tags: airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have been trying to set up airflow using the [official airflow helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-airflow/airflow) from artifacthub on a GKE cluster but coming up with a couple of issues.

First I get these errors from the pods:

```
Failed to load logs: container "scheduler" in pod "airflow-scheduler-6b6cc9db4-qmvbw" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
Reason: BadRequest (400)
```

Then from the init containers, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 39, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 138, in check_migrations
    db.check_migrations(timeout=args.migration_wait_timeout)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 739, in check_migrations
    f"There are still unapplied migrations after {timeout} seconds. Migration"
TimeoutError: There are still unapplied migrations after 60 seconds. MigrationHead(s) in DB: set() | Migration Head(s) in Source Code: {'ecb43d2a1842'}
```

The postgres pods look okay.

The second issue is that I get the error that the pods are not scheduled because no nodes are available, and the cluster doesn't autoscale because even after that, the nodes will not contain the new pods.

The challenge with the above is that I upgraded the nodes to have 32 processors and 64GB memory, but the error persists. So I assume it is something else.

Comment: Can you confirm that the nodes actually exist in GKE?

Comment: Yes, the nodes exist. I even have ingress-nginx and cert-manager deployed on the cluster.